Add security to embedded Jetty 12
I'm trying to add security to an embedded Jetty 12 server.
What works:

I can surf to /, and I get my landing page without authentication
I can surf to /web, and it gets the proper webpage, and makes a websocket connection, both without authentication
If I surf to /model, it dispatches to my login page
If I put in bad credentials, it returns to my login page

What doesn't work:

If I put in good credentials, it goes to my / main landing page; I'd like it to continue on to /model
If I subsequently surf to /model, it still shows my login page.  I cannot ever get to /model

Here is my code:
    public WebsocketServer(int port, Model model, SessionManager sessionManager) throws Exception {
        server_ = new Server(port);
        server_.setRequestLog(new CustomRequestLog(new Slf4jRequestLogWriter(), CustomRequestLog.EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT));


        SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
        server_.setHandler(sessionHandler);


        ConstraintSecurityHandler security = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
        sessionHandler.setHandler(security);

        HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService("login");
        try (ResourceFactory.Closeable rf = ResourceFactory.closeable()) {
            Path pw = Paths.get("cfg/web.passwords");
            log_.info("Configuring login passwords from {} {}", pw, pw.toFile().exists());
            Resource r = rf.newResource(pw);
            loginService.setConfig(r);
            security.setLoginService(loginService);
        }
        FormAuthenticator formAuthenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/login", "/login", true);
        //formAuthenticator.setAlwaysSaveUri(true);
        security.setAuthenticator(formAuthenticator);


        ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
        cm.setPathSpec("/model/*");
        cm.setConstraint(Constraint.from("admin"));
        security.setConstraintMappings(Collections.singletonList(cm));


        ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
        security.setHandler(contextHandlerCollection);


        // add a context for /model
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/model");

        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ModelServlet(model)), "/*");
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(servletContextHandler);


        // add a context for /web
        servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/web");
        servletContextHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"websocket.html"});

        Resource webResource = ResourceFactory.of(servletContextHandler).newResource(Paths.get("cfg/web"));
        if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(webResource))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find web resource");

        ServletHolder holderWeb = new ServletHolder("web", DefaultServlet.class);
        holderWeb.setInitParameter("baseResource", webResource.getURI().toASCIIString());
        holderWeb.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");
        holderWeb.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(holderWeb, "/*");

        // allow websocket upgrades in this context
        JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(servletContextHandler, (context, configurator) ->
        {
            configurator.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30000));
            configurator.addMapping("/ws", (req, res) -> {
                Session s = new Session(req);
                sessionManager.add(s);
                return s;
            });
        });
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(servletContextHandler);


        // add a context for the login page
        servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/login");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FormAuthServlet()), "/*");
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(servletContextHandler);


        // add a context for the root
        servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        Resource baseResource = ResourceFactory.of(servletContextHandler).newResource(Paths.get("cfg/web"));
        if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(baseResource))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find base resource");
        servletContextHandler.setBaseResource(baseResource);
        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder("root", DefaultServlet.class);
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
        contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(servletContextHandler);


        server_.start();
        //server.join();
    }


(As an aside, I don't know if I'm chaining Session, Security, and ContextHandlers correctly)
